# Oracle+ Dapper (c#). Как выполнить процедуру из package в Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

Есть пакет в БД Oracle, в котором создана процедура. Через sqldeveloper выполнется процедура через запрос

```
exec Pack.Procedure()
```

Есть приложение на C#, где используем Dapper. Но если написать код в виде:

```
string query = "exec Pack.Procedure()";
DBController.GetDbConnection().Execute(query, CommandType.StoredProcedure)
```

То выдаст ошибку *ex: ORA-00900: неверно предложение на языке SQL*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837539/syntax-error-while-trying-to-call-an-oracle-package-using-odbc-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел, в коде надо было прописать не exec, а call

```
string query = "call Pack.Procedure()";
DBController.GetDbConnection().Execute(query, CommandType.StoredProcedure)
```